# Adding Views dynamically in Linear Layout in Fragment

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments, dynamically-generated

I am trying to add TextView to the nested linearLayout in fragmentin onCreateView, I don't know if this is the correct approach or not, new to android!
Thanks in advance

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_screen_slide_page, container, false);
    List<LifeBerrysXmlParser.Item> items = (ArrayList<LifeBerrysXmlParser.Item>) getArguments().getSerializable("List");
    TextView mainHeading = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.mainHeading);
    ImageView mainImage = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.articleMainImage);
    LinearLayout articleLayout = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.articleLayout);
    TextView tev = new TextView(getActivity());
    tev.setText("Hello..............");
    articleLayout.addView(tev);
    LifeBerrysXmlParser.Item item = items.get(getArguments().getInt("position"));
    String articleMainHeading = item.mainHeading;
    String articlemainImage = item.mainImage;
    mainHeading.setText(articleMainHeading);
    if (!articlemainImage.isEmpty()) {
        Picasso.with(getContext()).load(articlemainImage).into(mainImage);
    }
    return rootView;
}
```

can anyone please help me what I am doing wrong?

here is my xml for the fragment

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:padding="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:scrollIndicators="right">
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/articleMainImage"
                    android:maxHeight="300dp"/>
                <TextView
                    style="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightLarge"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.2"
                    android:id="@+id/mainHeading"
                    android:textColor="#ff6435"
                    android:clickable="false"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
            </RelativeLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/articleLayout"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Read More"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:onClick="readMore"
                    android:padding="1dp"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_light" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Do you receive some errors, or `TextView` just doesn't show?

Comment: No errors, just textView is not visible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have mistake in your article layout. Your article layout has horizontal orientation, and it's child TextView has `match_parent` width, so when you add new child, it'll be outside the screen. Change orientation to vertical:

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/articleLayout"
            android:orientation="vertical">      <---- Change this line
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Read More"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:onClick="readMore"
                android:padding="1dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_light" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It Worked but I want child views in horizontal layout and dynamic textView above the already existed TextView!

Comment: I think, you should try to reduce number of Linear and Relative layouts, it'll be good for performance and clean code.

Comment: I want to do something like this:

`for (int i = 0; i< description.size(); i++){
            TextView articleHeading = new TextView(getActivity());
            articleHeading.setText(item.heading.get(i));
            articleLayout.addView(articleHeading);
//            ImageView articleImage = new ImageView(getActivity());
//            Picasso.with(getContext()).load(item.image.get(i)).into(articleImage);
            articleLayout.addView(articleHeading);
//            articleLayout.addView(articleImage);
        }`
 [logcat](http://pastebin.com/jgRrfSmR)

Comment: You are trying to add same `articleHeading` to `articleLayout` two times. One View can **only** be added once to `ViewGroup`

Comment: making array of articleHeading Textview would do? @RediOne1

Comment: Read about `ListView` + `BaseAdapter` or `RecyclerView` + `RecyclerView.Adapter`, this'll be best way to display list of content.